# Typescript Material UI beta version 11 Grid

Tags: material-ui

I am using typescript and material-ui in my project.
After upgrade to version v1.0.0-beta.11, now I am not able to add className in Grid Component

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same issue but try upgrading to material-ui v1.0.0-beta.12 it seems to have been resolved.